# Live Stream from GoPro 4 Session to Android unoffically

Tags: android, live-streaming, gopro

I am developing an Android app to get the live stream from a GoPro 4 Session to the app.

In previous GoPro models, the live stream can be got by the URL request http://10.5.5.9:8080/live/aaba.m3u8

However, in GoPro Hero 4 models, the URL request has been changed to http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/execute?p1=gpStream&c1=start

And it requires ffplay and a python script to keep the streaming alive.

I would like to know if this can be done in an Android app.

I do not need to have a good quality and smooth streaming as I only need to get the view of the camera.

I have the idea of configuring the GoPro to Picture mode and take picture at 1 second interval. Then get the image from 100GOPRO/DCIM on the Android app per second. Can this be done in Android also?

Thanks anyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself so far but I found a comprehensive github repository sharing streaming information about many GoPro cameras: https://github.com/KonradIT/goprowifihack

1. wake up the session first like described [here](https://github.com/KonradIT/goprowifihack/blob/master/HERO4/HERO4-Session.md)
2. Restart the stream with http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/execute?p1=gpStream&a1=proto_v2&c1=restart
3. Then stream via udp://10.5.5.9:8554 [source](https://github.com/KonradIT/goprowifihack/blob/master/HERO4/Livestreaming.md)

Comment: The repo is updated to support Hero 4 Session which may solve my problem! :)

Comment: Please keep me informed if it worked, I am also interested in solving the problem

Comment: I am able to wake up the 4 session and trying to implement the live streaming feature.

Comment: I am able to live stream now but the delay is still unacceptable.

Comment: The delay is within 1 second now which is acceptable. @PhilLab

Comment: Thanks for the updates, how did you get the delay down?

Comment: Hi guys, I'm trying to develop an android app too, what are you using to read the udp stream?

Comment: @ErikMinarini : i'm trying to dev android app streaming via gopro, are you find solution streaming udp

Comment: @HoangQBH unfortunately not, I've tried with Vitamio but it seems not working. Actually, I'm looking for a good solution, Have you any idea?